# Commutative semigroup, ring, commutative ring of functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have problems solving the following:

Let $G$ be a commutative semigroup, $R$ a ring and define

$R[G] = \{ f: G \rightarrow R \ | \ card \{g \in G \ | \ f(g) \neq 0 \} < \infty \}$.

Addition is standard : $(f_1+f_2)(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x)$

And multiplication is defined like this: $(f_1 \cdot f_2)(x) = \sum _{g_1g_2=x} f_1(g_1) \cdot f_2(g_2)$

So this is a set of functions from $G$ to $R$ which aren't $0$ only for a finite number of $g$'s.

I need to prove that it is a commutative ring.

It's obvious that it is an abelian group, without using the fact that $G$ is a semigroup (or at least I think I didn't use that). If $f \in R[G] \Rightarrow -f \in R[G]$ and $f=0$ is the addition identity here.

I think this structure is closed under multiplication, because if we multiply a nonzero value by a nonzero value, we get a nonzero value (and this can happen only finitely many times) and if we multiply a value by a zero value, we get zero, so nothing bad happens.

I have serious problems proving that multiplication is commutative.

Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help if we simplified the task a little. Consider the functions $\hat{g}:G\to R$
 which are $1$ at $g$ and zero elsewhere.

To make a function which is $r$ at $g$ instead, you just use the function $r\hat{g}=\hat{g}r$. You can get a new function from $G$ into $R$ at any time by multiplying by an element of $R$ like this.

What do these look like when we apply the definition of multiplication? Well, $(r\hat{g})(s\hat{h})$ is only nonzero at $gh$, where it has value $rs$, and that means $(r\hat{g})(s\hat{h})=rs(\widehat{gh})$

What about a function that is nonzero on more places? Since there are only finitely many nonzero places, you can get any function you want by adding finitely many of the functions we've already mentioned: $\sum r_g\hat{g}$. Every function decomposes this way.

But then look: if you prove that $r\hat{g}\cdot s\hat{h}=s\hat{h}\cdot r\hat{g}$ for all $r,s\in R$ and $g,h\in G$, then after distributing a product $(\sum r_g\hat{g})(\sum s_h\hat{h})$ out to $(r_g\hat{g})(s_h\hat{h})=r_gs_h(\widehat{gh})$, it becomes obvious that if $R$ and $G$ have commutative multiplication, these little terms commute and so does the whole product.

---

In my humble opinion, the functional representation of the semigroup ring obscures this fact more than the "formal construction" of $R[G]$ does.

In that scheme, we formally make elements of the form $\sum r_gg$ where $r_g\in R$ and $g\in G$, and only finitely many of the $r_g$ are nonzero. Addition and multiplication are defined in the obvious ways: you add on "like terms" (elements of $G$) and multiplication is just distributively multiplying these sums like you would for polynomials.

This is equivalent to the hints I gave with the $\hat{g}$ above. Just as the $g$ formally generate this construction, the $\hat{g}$ generated the functional construction.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to think about that.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand this construction now, except for one thing. I have one question about multiplying the functions by an element of the ring. 
Why can we do that? Secondly, will it suffice to say that $ (r\hat{g})(s\hat{h})=rs(\widehat{gh})=sr(\widehat{gh})$ so it has value $sr$ at $gh$, so $=s\hat{h}\cdot r\hat{g}$ ?

Comment: @Axl Sure, there's nothing wrong with defining $r\cdot f:G \to R$ to mean the map $g\mapsto rf(g)$ for all $g\in G$. I think what you wrote is basically all you need, but you did mean to mention that $\widehat{gh}=\widehat{hg}$ when $G$ is commutative right?

Comment: Yes, if $\widehat{gh}$ has value $1$ for $gh$, then, because $gh=hg$, it has value $1$ for $hg$, so $\widehat{gh}=\widehat{hg}$. Is it the correct argument?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem. If $R$ is commutative then $$(f_1 \cdot f_2)(x) = \sum _{g_1+g_2=x} f_1(g_1) \cdot f_2(g_2)= \sum _{g_2+g_1=x} f_2(g_2) \cdot f_1(g_1)=(f_2 \cdot f_1)(x).$$

If $R$ is not commutative, $ab\ne ba$, then set $f_1(x)=f_2(x)=0$ for $x\ne 1$ (for simplicity I suppose that $G$ has an identity element) and $f_1(1)=a$, $f_2(1)=b$, then $f_1\cdot f_2\ne f_2\cdot f_1$.

Comment: That's true. But could you explain to me why you can assume that this semigroup has an identity element. I understand that here you use it to express $x=y+1$. Can I similarly suppose that there exists an element $a \in G$ such that for this element both functions have a nonzero value? And then say that for $x=y+a$ multiplication isn't commutative?

Comment: I can't upvote your answer, because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you use the addition for $G$, not the multiplication. In this case I suppose that $G$ has a zero: $x+0=x$.

Comment: My question is the same. Why can we suppose that $G$ has a zero? Is my understanding of why multiplication is not commutative correct?

Comment: I mean is it true that the finite set described in the question isn't closed under addition?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. If you suppose that $R$ is commutative, then multiplication in $R[G]$ is commutative regardless of existence $0(1)$ in $G$.

Comment: But if I don't assume that $R$ is commutative, then $R[G]$ also isn't commutative. Could you explain to me more why that is?

Comment: OK, let $R$ is not commutative. Then I  show in the answer that $R[G]$ also is not commutative for the case when $G$ contains the identity element $0_G$.

Comment: Yes, and I understand that argument. I only have doubts whether we can assume that there exists a zero in the semigroup $G$. What if there isn't a zero in $G$?

Comment: I don't know. There is a lot of diverse semigroups...

Comment: @Axl What do you mean by "zero in $G$"? Do you mean an absorbing element $zg=z$ for all $g\in G$?

Comment: No, I mean an element such that $x=x+0$. What can we do if there isn't such an element in $G$? As I see, it we can set nonzero values for $0$ but take $x$ which has zero value for both functions, then we can see that multiplication isn't commutative.

Comment: Yes, I know. Is there any way to prove that $R[G]$ isn't commutative when $G$ is an arbitrary commutative semigroup?

Comment: @Axl No, if $G$ and $R$ are commutative, then so is $R[G]$. I'm still trying to understand the last comment too. Are you denoting the operation in $G$ by $+$?

Comment: $G$ is the semigroup on which the functions are defined. In the definition of multiplication in $R[G]$ we add elements of $G$, so I thought that the operation in $G$ is addition.

Comment: Dear @Axl : Ah, we need to address that then! No, the $+$ and $\cdot$ in the definition of multiplication is the $+$ and $\cdot$ *in* $R$.

Comment: You mean that $g_1+g_2=x$ is in $R$? I can see that the elements of $R[G]$ are in a way "polynomials" only defined on a commutative semigroup instead of $\mathbb{N}^n$

Comment: @Axl Oh, sorry, I see you put a $+$ sign in the subscript now too. I thought you were talking about the summation of the $f_1(g_1)\cdot f_2(g_2)$. I really think it would be much better to use $g_1g_2=x$ in that subscript instead of $+$. It really seems less confusing to simply remember $G$ is commutative rather than introduce a $+$ to confuse with the $+$ in $R$.

Comment: Ok, I'll change that right now.